# error 404 Communication servlet/JSP in a form

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a simple form with name and password. But when I click on validate button on my form called "inscription", I get an error 404. My error is : ETAT 404 HTTP-/inscription
type: Rapport d'état
message:/inscription
description: ressource not available
That's all I have.

I should get a blank page instead because there is nothing in my post method.

Here is my **NEW** JSP file inscription.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Inscription</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/inc/style.css"/>" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/inscription">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Inscription</legend>
                <p>Vous pouvez vous inscrire via ce formulaire.</p>

                <label for="email">Adresse email <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" size="20" maxlength="60" />
                <br />

                <label for="motdepasse">Mot de passe <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" id="motdepasse" name="motdepasse" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                <br />

                <label for="confirmation">Confirmation du mot de passe <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" id="confirmation" name="confirmation" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                <br />

                <label for="nom">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" />
                <br />

                <input type="submit" value="Inscription" class="sansLabel" />
                <br />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my **NEW** servlet Inscription.java:

```
package com.sdzee.pro.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Inscription
 */
@WebServlet( "/inscription" )
public class Inscription extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long  serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String VUE              = "/WEB-INF/inscription.jsp";

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Inscription() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append( "Served at: " ).append( request.getContextPath() );
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response );

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet( request, response );
    }

}
```

And here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Inscription</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sdzee.pro.servlets.Inscription</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Inscription</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/inscription</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

error 404 means the resource you're trying to access cannot be found. So it's a problem with your url mapping for your Servlet.

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value="/inscription"/>">
```

This is incorrect, you need to escape the quotes like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value=\"inscription\">">
```

But if you know your URL mapping, why not just hardcode it with the relative path? ('..' is for going up a directory)

```
<form method="post" action="../inscription">
```

**EDIT:**

Just noticed an inconsistency with your url-mapping...

in your web.xml it is:

```
 <url-pattern>/inscription</url-pattern>
```

But you have an servlet annotation as:

```
@WebServlet( "/Inscription" )
```

This will also bring you problems. Make sure these are the same. Change the annotation to match your web.xml servlet mapping:

```
@WebServlet( "/inscription" )
```

URL Servlet mapping is case sensitive.

Comment: It doesn't work with <form method="post" action="../inscription"> and <form method="post" action="<c:url value=\"inscription\">">
. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: edit your question and include the whole error you get please

Comment: @Slim check out my edited answer, found your other problem.

Comment: It still doesn't work, even after modification you told me to do.

Comment: Restart the server. Make sure url mappings are the same for annotations and web.xml. Post the error code you are getting so we can actually see what is wrong if the problem is still there.